# Fubini's theorem for complex measures?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Recall that Fubini's theorem in a very basic form says that if $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\lambda)$ are $\sigma$-finite *positive* measure spaces and $f$ is a positive function on $X \times Y$ that is measurable with respect to the product measure, then 
$$\int_X (\int_Y f(x,y) d \lambda(y)) d\mu(x) = \int_Y (\int_X f(x,y) d \mu(x)) d \lambda(y).$$

I am curious, what happens in Fubini's theorem if we remove the requirement that the measures are positive, and instead assume that they are complex Borel measures? Does some version of Fubini's theorem still hold? If not, can we put more requirements on either $f$ or the measures to make it work for complex Borel measures? My guess would be that it would be good to look at the Radon-Nikodym theorem to show that something similar holds, but I am not sure.

Comment: The thing you call a very basic form of Fubini is actually Tonelli's Theorem - Fubini is slightly different. They both have versions for complex measures - I don't think you want to try to use Radon-Nikodym, instead just note that if $\mu$ is a complex measure then there exist positive measures $\mu_j$ such that $\mu=(\mu_1-\mu_2)+i(\mu_3-\mu_4)$, and (for the sake of clarifying what the hypotheses in _Fubini_ should be) $|\mu|\le\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+\mu_4$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The requirements for a complex version for Tonelli (and Fubini to hold) would thus be for each $\mu_i$  to be $\sigma$-finite? Or are weaker conditions enough? If it is required that each $\mu_i$ is $\sigma$-finite, can we put some requirements on $\mu$ to make that hold?

Comment: Actually the more II think about it the more it seems any version of Tonelli for complex measures is going to be much weaker than the standard Tonelli. We should concentrate on Fubini. A generalization of Fubini is very straighforward. Except first you have to get straight what the standard Fubini actually _says_ - so far your one statement of Fubini's theorem was _not_ actually Fubini! What _is_ the standard version of Fubini, exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Just to avoid writing down all the hypotheses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#For_integrable_functions Is what I would call the standard version of the Fubini.
Once again, we require $\sigma$-finiteness and positiveness of the measures. Would you agree that this is the standard version of Fubini?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Also, if $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure, of course it is true that, both the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$ are finite measures. It seems to me that the positive and negative parts of the real and imaginary parts must then be finite as well, so that $\mu_i$ are all $\sigma$-finite (even finite) for complex Borel measures. The problem is of course, in Tonelli, that in integrating $f$ by first doing the negative part, and then the positive part etc. is that we might run into expressions like $\infty-\infty$ which we can not make sense of.

Comment: For Fubini, such problems should not occur, since we already assume that the integral is finite.

Comment: RIght on both counts. Of course you still  haven't actually stated Fubini's theorem, but it sounds like you know what the correct statement is. The generalization to complex measures is immediate: Assuming $f(x,y)$ is measurable, if $\mu_X$ and $\mu_Y$ are complex measures and $\int_X\int_Y|f|d|\mu_X|d|\mu_Y|<\infty$ then it works. (Note you can use the standard Tonelli to verify the integrability, since $|\mu_X|$ and $|\mu_Y|$ are positive measures. Also note you can omit the $\sigma$-finite hypothesis! Because if $\mu$ is a complex measure then $|\mu|$ is automatically finite.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your answer. If you want to post it as an  answer for points, you are welcome to do so and I will accept your answer.