# Fubini's for complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Firstly, I understand this question may have been asked here [Fubini's theorem for complex measures?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604915/fubinis-theorem-for-complex-measures), but I am not so familiar with some of the theory used in the answer.

My question regards the application of Fubini's theorem (or a specific case, involving swapping sums and integrals). I am under the impression that:

$$\int_{a}^{b} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k, x) \text{dx} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(k,x) \text{dx}$$ If and only if either $\int_{a}^{b} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} |f(k, x)| \text{dx}$ or $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} |f(k,x)| \text{dx}$ is bounded, where $|x|$ is the absolute function defined on the reals.

My confusion then arises when trying to apply this to $f(k,x) = e^{kix}$ where I am trying to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{kix}}{k!} \text{dx}$$.

I found that the integral evaluates to $2\pi$, by writing $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{kix}}{k!} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{kix}}{k!}$ and making the claim that $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{kix}}{k!} \text{dx} = 0$, which seems obvious intuitively. However, I run into problems when trying to prove this rigourously. Firstly, the absolute function is not defined on complex numbers. I have no justification for using the magnitude of the complex number in place. Secondly, if I try to swap the integral and the sum, without dealing with the $k=0$ index, the result I get is different. How can Fubini's be applied with complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, Fubini's Theorem  (and DCT) are all valid for complex functions and the proof is by applying the real case to real and imaginary parts.

Comment: (And the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) is also defined for complex numbers.) But beware that (on real numbers as well as complex ones) the theorem is an "if", not "if and only if".

Comment: What is the "different result" you got?