# Finding dual operator - applying Fubinis theorem

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory

For X=Y=$C([0,1])$ find the dual operator $T^*$ of $Tf(t)=\int_0^tf(s)ds$

Using the Riesz representation theorem we get $$\int_0^1f(s)d\nu(s)=T_\mu^*(f)=\int_0^1(\int_0^tf(s)ds)\;d\mu(t).$$
Now I'd like to apply the Fubini's theorem on the left hand side so I have the function $f$ in the first integral and that way I should be able to get the dual operator, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: $d\nu (s)=\mu ([s,1]) ds$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, if $T:C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$, then $T':C([0,1])'\to C([0,1])'$ is defined by

$$(T'\ell)(f)=\ell(Tf).$$

Fix an $\ell\in C([0,1])'$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there exists a unique complex regular Borel measure $\mu_\ell:\mathscr{B}([0,1])\to\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$\ell(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_\ell$$

for all $f\in C([0,1])$. In particular we get that

$$(T'\ell)(f)=\ell(Tf)=\int_{[0,1]}\int_0^t f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}\mu_\ell(t)$$

for all $f\in C([0,1])$. Fix an $f\in C([0,1])$, and observe that then $\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq C$ for some $C>0$. Observe then that

$$\int_{[0,1]}\int_0^1\lvert \chi_{[0,t]}(x)f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}\lvert\mu_\ell\rvert(t)\leq C\lvert\mu_\ell\rvert([0,1])<\infty,$$

so by Fubini's theorem (valid in this form for complex measures, which can easily be proven by decomposing the complex measure, see for example [the comments on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2604915/fubinis-theorem-for-complex-measures)) we have that, by observing that $\chi_{[0,t]}(x)=\chi_{[x,1]}(t)$ for all $x,t\in[0,1]$,

$$(T'\ell)(f)=\int_0^1\int_{[x,1]}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\mu_\ell(t)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1f(x)\mu_\ell([x,1])\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Define the complex regular Borel measure $\nu:\mathscr{B}([0,1])\to\mathbb{C}$ by

$$\nu(A)=\int_A\mu_\ell([x,1])\,\mathbb{d}x$$

and observe that the above then states that

$$(T'\ell)(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f\,\mathrm{d}\nu.$$

Appealing once again to the Riesz Representation Theorem, this time applied to $T'\ell$, we get the representation

$$(T'\ell)(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_{T'\ell}.$$

As this measure is unique, this then implies that

$$\mu_{T'\ell}(A)=\nu(A)=\int_A\mu_\ell([x,1])\,\mathrm{d}x$$

for all $A\in\mathscr{B}([0,1])$. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer, this is exactly was needed. It didn't occur to me to use the characteristic function to remove the variable from the boundary and therefore I wasn't able to proceed, but this explains everything.

Comment: Also, please, could you also expand a bit on the last line, $\mu_{T'l}(A)=\int_{A}\mu_l([x,1])dx$? I understand your solution until this point. @Lorago

Comment: @Weyr124 I've updated my answer, hopefully this makes it clearer! I just appeal to the uniqueness part of the Riesz Representation Theorem. Alternatively you could prove it directly using that characteristic functions can be approximated by continuous functions